# android studio can not show all the packages in a jar file

Tags: android, zxing

I am studying zxing project these days. but when I add core-3.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to both eclipse and Android studio, they show different content.  Some of the packages fails to show in Android Studio. For example, the "com.google.zxing.common.reedsolomon" package is "missing". How to show all the packages in Android Studio? Please help me, thank you very much.

these are the packages shown in the eclipse
[image]

these are the packages and classes shown in android studio
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android studio go to the top left corner and change the view of Android studio from **Android** to **Project**
Please refer [this](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-EXOtA-BBsRA/V1K-UsEwUdI/AAAAAAAAAkQ/RPLqbRkL0ugksOYeam8LpJuZIkUaUHzdACLcB/s1600/project%2BWindow.png) for more info. Selecting project view you need to collapse **External Libraries** option there you will get the package view of every library.

Comment: thank you. and yes, all the java files are presented in android studio, just presented in different style from eclipse.